# Using <input oninput= ... with current value in textbox

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an simple HTML input tag inside my React component, defined thusly:

```
<input type="text" onInput={(value) => {
                search(value);
                return value;
            }}/>
```

By using `oninput`, I am hoping to invoke the `search` method, with the current value in the textbox as an argument, whenever the value in in the textbox is changed. The `search` method is defined in the same component thusly:

```
const search = _.debounce((value) => {
                    doSomething(value);
                 }, 500);
```

When I debug in Chrome Dev Tools, I see that `value` has the following value, instead of the current value in the textbox:

```
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]] : SyntheticEvent
[[IsRevoked]] : false
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I call search and provide it the current value in the textbox as an argument? Online examples show `oninput` being used like `<input type="text" oninput="myFunction()">`, but they don't show how to pass the value in your textbox as input to the function called on the `oninput` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter of your `onInput` function is a JavaScript `Event` object. To extract the value of it, you have to first bind the value of the input box to something:

```
<input
  type="text"
  value={this.state.value}
  onInput={this.handleSearch}
/>
```

And then in your component methods, extract this value with `event.target`, which allows you to look at the DOM elements properties (we want the `value` property):

```
handleSearch(event) {
  this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  this.search(event.target.value); // Or wherever your search method is
}
```

EDIT: renamed search => handleSearch to avoid confusion :)